# Probleme of pagination (Laravel)

Tags: laravel

I have a problem with my pagination, i have my every page displayed, when i want go to other page my search is canceled and it displays all the elements of the site.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Furniture;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Tag;

class MainController extends Controller
{
    public function showHomepage()
    {
        $latestProducts = Furniture::latest()->take(5)->get();

        return view('templates.homepage', compact('latestProducts'));
    }

    public function showFurniture(Furniture $furniture)
    {
        return view('templates.furniture', compact('furniture'));
    }

    public function showSearchResults(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->get('q');
        $tag = Tag::where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->first();

            $query = Furniture::select("furniture.*")
            ->join("furniture_tag", "furniture_tag.furniture_id", "=", "furniture.id");
            if ($tag){
                $query->where('furniture_tag.tag_id', $tag->id);
            }
            $query->orWhere('furniture.title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            $furnituresCount=$query->count();
            $furnitures=$query->paginate(5);

            return view('templates.search', compact('search', 'furnitures', 'furnituresCount',));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append all of the current request's query string values to the pagination links you need to change

```
$furnitures=$query->paginate(5);
```

to

```
$furnitures = $query->paginate(5)->withQueryString();
```

Manual: [Appending Query String Values](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#appending-query-string-values)